# Bob and Alice card game.

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to find a solution for the following problem:

> Bob and Alice play the following game:
> Given $n$ cards arranged in a line, all with positive integers, each player on its turn, collects one card from one end of the line, to its choice, until no cards are left.
> The player with the highest sum wins.

I am trying to find a algorithm to determine if bob *can* win for sure, for any series of moves of alice.

I was able to solve this problem using dynamic programming, by checking all the options.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: So, all the numbers are visible?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, But its irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, dynamic programming is the way to go.

Define the table with entries $T_A([i,j])$ (and $T_B([i,j])$ respectively) denoting the optimum value for Alice (and Bob respectively), when there are only the cards $i$ to $j$ left (meaning cards $1-i$ and $j+1-n$ have already been picked up and $i < j$) and it is Alice's turn (resp. Bob's). The idea for $T_A([i,j])$ is that Alice can get either $v_i$ or $v_j$ ($v_k$ being the value of card $k$) plus all cards from $i+1$ to $j$ (if she picks up card $i$) *minus* what Bob will pick up.
Then $T_A([i,j]) = \max\{v_j + \sum_{\ell=i}^{j-1} v_\ell - T_B([i,j-1]), v_i + \sum_{\ell=i+1}^{j} v_\ell - T_B([i+1,j])\}$.
Similarly for Bob (T_B).

Here, this dynamic program "assumes" that both Alice and Bob are playing optimally (trying to maximise their gain at every step). But since all resources are being distributed among the two anyways, if Alice does not maximise her gain, then Bob will get the difference (the optimum for Alice minus what she picked in the end). In other words, if Alice does not maximise her gain at every step, Bob will only get more.

Assuming Alice starts before Bob, to check if Bob can get more than Alice, we simply check whether $T_A(1,n) \geq (\sum_{i=1}^n v_i)/2$. This does not hold if and only if Bob gets strictly more than half of the total resources, meaning he gets more than Alice.